# Open Google Search with Keyboard Shortcut (Windows 8)

Tags: windows-7, windows-8, google-chrome, keyboard, keyboard-shortcuts

Anyone know how to make a custom keyboard shortcut which will open Chrome (my default browser) at any time?  I have set a shortcut to open chrome from the "Properties" dialog (by right-clicking the Chrome icon in my taskbar, clicking properties, then filling in the keyboard shortcut).  Unfortunately, if the browser is already open, then this sometimes causes the window to open in the background, which is not what I want.  I want the shortcut to always cause the browser to open in the foreground.

If at all possible, I want to do this without 3rd party apps...

Thanks!

Comment: And. once you find an answer which works for you, clicking on the check mark to its right shows other users it worked for you, and thereby improves this knowledge base, as well as providing a small yet relevant egoboo to the poster of the solution.

Answer (score 0):

Use the Microsoft Mouse and Keyboard Center.

From the Control Panel, tap System and Security to open the Action Center, and then tap Install.

Once installed, create a macro.

Click the button or key you want to configure to run the macro.

If you have already created macros, a list will display under the Macro command. Click the one you want to assign to the button or key.

If you have not created any macros, click Not yet assigned and then click Create a new macro.

The Macro Editor now appears.

In the File Name box, type a name for your macro.

Click the Editor box, and enter your macro. Most keystrokes can be typed in directly with your keyboard.

Click Back to save the macro and return to the previous screen.